# Glide caching for different image in same URL

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-glide

I use [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) library to get image from server. My problem is that when image updated in server with same URL for previous image, Glide show the previous image.
I added these lines to my code but the problem remained:

```
.skipMemoryCache(true)
.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
.signature(new ObjectKey(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
```

My full code is:

```
CircleImageView profileImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_image_view);
GlideApp.with(view.getContext())
                .load(sessionManager.getAvatar().replace("https", "http"))
                .error(R.drawable.default_pic)
                .skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
                .signature(new ObjectKey(String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_camera)
                .centerCrop()
                .into(profileImageView);
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Glide 4.x`, try to do:

```
var requestOptions = RequestOptions()
    requestOptions.skipMemoryCache(true)
    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)
    .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()))
    Glide.with(this).load(url).apply(requestOptions).into(this)
```

So create a `RequestOptions()` object and apply desired flags trough it

Comment: Not working. I tried:  RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions()
                    .signature(new ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis()));

           
            CircleImageView profileImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.profile_picture_image_view);
            Glide.with(view.getContext())
                    .load(sessionManager.getAvatar().replace("https", "http"))
                    .apply(requestOptions)
                    .into(profileImageView);

Comment: did you add `.skipMemoryCache(true)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE)` too? (See my edited answer) @behrooz.fard

Answer (score 0):

Glide caches images for a certain period of time, after which they are automatically removed from the cache. The default cache expiration time for Glide is **2 minutes**. However, you can configure the cache expiration time according to your needs by using the diskCacheStrategy() method.

To set the cache expiration time to 7 days, you can use the following code:

```
Glide.with(context)
        .load(url)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.AUTOMATIC)
        .override(width, height)
        .skipMemoryCache(true)
        .signature(ObjectKey(System.currentTimeMillis() / (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))))
        .into(imageView)
```

Answer (score -1):

**Try these alternatives**

> **Solution 1**

:- Use Picasso

**Example code**

Gradle here

```
 implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

> Usage:-

```
Picasso.get().load("url_here).into(profileImageView);
```

> **Solution 2**:-

```
// DownloadImage AsyncTask
    private class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... URL) {

            String imageURL = URL[0];

            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            try {
                // Download Image from URL
                InputStream input = new java.net.URL(imageURL).openStream();
                // Decode Bitmap
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            // set bitmap to imageview here
            }
        }
    }
```

**Usage:**

```
// Execute DownloadImage AsyncTask
     new DownloadImage().execute("url_here");
```